# Reason behind geography based language restrictions on digital content in online stores

Tags: marketing

I live in Europe, but I am not European. And I would like to pay for digital content (movies). But if you take a quick look at the digital services here, then you start to understand that that is impossible to do. Google Play only sells movies in Italian in Italy, German French and Italian for the Swiss, French for the French, so on and so forth.

Don't get me wrong, I would still not pay for a horribly dubbed movie even if I were French, because to me even the best dubs are horrible, as dubbing generally reduces a lot of linguistic nuances buried within the original language, and these you can get a feel of from the context and tone. Or in the words of Sheldon Cooper, "In a world where I have heard the voice of the real Angelina Jolie, why would I settle for a fake Angelina Jolie?".

So my question is why. Why can't I buy movies in English? There is already a pre-existing question like that on the google forums. But the answer is cryptic. It states that content owners decide which language is available on the google play store.

So there's the question, **Why don't content owners allow the availability of Original language movies on online stores?**

They want to make money and I want to give them my money. So why won't they take it?

Comment: Even if people preferring original version and not dubbed one is increasing, it's not the case for the majority yet. I'll may suggest to go to another provider that may help you with that issue. It's not that much uncommon that version are offered in original/dubbed for the target country.

Comment: I understand that, but we are talking about digital content where providing a multi-lingual version is very simple, from a technical point of view. I have tried to find an alternate provider. But that's not the question. My question is what's stopping them? Technically, a simple matter. No logistics nightmares involved so Why not provide multi-lingual versions?

Comment: Maybe paying the dubbing is their issue (which for some movies, especially animated one is done by "known" actors/actress of the country), and I also, maybe because dubbine people are "famous", I mean, when I see Bruce Willis, if I'm watching a dubbed version, I'm expecting for that voice (which I guess may costs more than a random character).

Comment: Because región Locking is profitable somehow and contract negotiations between corporate executives vary on their whims.

Comment: This is a great question. I hope someone has the answer. I would love to learn what it is.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Half of this question is an angry personal rant.